# Hyperbolicity for algebraic varieties and relation to curves on them

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, hodge-theory, sg.symplectic-geometry

My question is related to several notions of hyperbolicity, applied to Kähler manifolds (projective, in general). Kähler hyperbolicity was introduced in [this paper of Gromov's](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-33/issue-1/K%C3%A4hler-hyperbolicity-and-L_2-Hodge-theory/10.4310/jdg/1214446039.full). He calls a Kähler manifold *Kähler hyperbolic* if the lift to the universal cover of the symplectic form(=imaginary part of hermitian metric) is the differential of a bounded $1$-form. A $1$-form is bounded if its norm is pointwise absolutely bounded (the norm is induced by the pull-back of the metric to the tangent space).

As he notes in the introduction, this notion implies Kobayashi hyperbolicity. My question is regarding the converse, namely to find an example of a Kobayashi hyperbolic manifold that isn't Kähler hyperbolic.

---

My guess is that an example of an algebraic variety with the properties described below exists (so it would be nice if an algebraic geometer could say a few things here).

For a Kähler hyperbolic manifold, Gromov proves that its Euler characteristic is $(-1)^n$, where $n$ is its *complex* dimension. He also shows a Kähler hyperbolic manifold has quasi-ample canonical bundle (namely, it has Kodaira dimension $n$). Another observation is that a Kähler hyperbolic manifold cannot have amenable fundamental group. So any algebraic variety which fails one of the above tests but still is Kobayashi hyperbolic would fit the bill.

For somewhat different reasons, I would be happier if this would be a projective variety, which also doesn't have any $(2,0)$ cohomology. As a side question, just to check my understanding, is it true that for a variety with no $(2,0)$ classes in cohomology, any homology class that comes from a map of a surface (pushing forward the fundamental class) can in fact be realized by some algebraic curve in the variety?

Comment: I think you mean "the sign of its Euler characteristic is $(-1)^n$"

Comment: You might have a look on a survey of Voisin http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~voisin/Articlesweb/harvard.pdf,  On some problems of Kobayashi and Lang

Comment: It is a conjecture by Kobayashi (open starting from dimension three) that projective hyperbolic manifolds have ample canonical bundle. In particular, conjecturally you won't be able to find such examples by finding hyperbolic manifolds with non maximal Kodaira dimension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a very general hypersurface $j \colon X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ of sufficiently high degree, $3 \leq n \leq 4$. Then $X$ is Kobayashi hyperbolic (Kobayashi actually conjectured that this is true for all $n$ and Siu recently outlined a strategy for proving this, see Diverietti's comment below).

On the other hand, Lefschetz hyperplane theorem says that the natural map

$\pi_1(X) \stackrel{j_*}{\longrightarrow} \pi_1(\mathbb{P}^n)$

is an isomorphism. Then $X$ is simply connected, in particular its fundamental group is amenable and so $X$ cannot be Kahler hyperbolic.

If $n=4$, the projective variety $X$ also satisfies your second request. If fact, again by Lefschetz theorem, see for instance [Dimca, Singularities and topology of hypersurfaces, Theorem 2.6 p. 151], for all $n \geq 4$ we also have an isomorphism

$H^2(\mathbb{P}^n) \stackrel{j^*}{\longrightarrow}  H^2(X)$.

Since $H^2(\mathbb{P}^n)=\mathbb{C}$,  Hodge decomposition yields

$H^{2,0}(X)=H^{0,2}(X)=0, \quad H^{1,1}(X)=\mathbb{C}$.

If Kobayashi's conjecture were true, then the hypersurfaces $X$ would provide examples in all dimensions.

Comment: Let's say that Siu indicated a quite precise strategy to prove that. Up to now, we have a full proof only for surfaces in $\mathbb P^3$ and threefolds in $\mathbb P^4$.
So your exemple works for the moment just for $n=4$.

Comment: Ok, thank you for pointing this out. By the way, Lefschetz is true also for $n=3$, so surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ are examples too. However, the computations on $H^{2,0}$ works only for $n \geq 4$. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Just a last comment, to be precise. This is not Siu's conjecture, this is the Kobayashi conjecture. The strategy to prove it is by Siu.

Comment: Fixed. By the way Diverietti, do you know any other examples?

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess I need to learn how to do computations, not only the statements of the theorems :)

Comment: Recently it has been proved by Damian Brotbek that generic projective complete intersections of high multi-degree are hyperbolic. These should give other examples.
Otherwise, what about subvarieties of complex tori which do not contain any translate of a sub-tours ?

Comment: If $A$ is a complex torus and $X$ an irreducible subvariety of $A$ which is non-degenerated, locally complete intersection and such that $2 \dim X > \dim A$, then $\pi_1(X)=\pi_1(A)$. So the fundamental group of $X$ is Abelian, hence amenable, in particular $X$ is not Kahler hyperbolic. If you know that $X$ is Kobayashi hyperbolic, this actually gives an example.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. A subvariety of a complex torus is Kobayashi hyperbolic if and only if it does not contain any translate of a subtorus